# unable to fetch manager detail using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I want to use Microsoft Graph to fetch manager details from my C# based bot.

I am able to fetch my profile by using this query:

```
await new HttpClient()
    .GetWithAuthAsync(token.AccessToken,
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/");
```

but when I try to fetch the manager, I am getting not able to get a response:

```
await new HttpClient()
    .GetWithAuthAsync(token.AccessToken,
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/abc@domain.com/manager");
```

I am unable to understand what is wrong with the query
please help.

Please find below access token:

```
https://9c9ca0db.ngrok.io/api/OAuthCallback?code=AQABAAIAAADX8GCi6Js6SK82TsD2Pb7rgKFM6GqiboAOn6WZitAqMLG2xkiduiMIz1slVYvjSZeevZcHogj8vmYwZH1JfaqgX1CXsBs2l7bCn1lwhZh2bq6B4LlxeJWku8zZI5hiY2mLReHWWiuQtZp4J5JJ_RVvbe6eBfgsamlCYhRPKMAfsuRBri-mQ5nJCYmVkdYOY6aGxblY2mzZL85mwogRECROLc0PsQohR1Sw0rRTon7JvHl8Pc5-GxxFYwtClp66EWnhoy8FV5dFBSOfOS_wNcijwKkA-RXvaZ2yscOnfCOKRaEL2FAUm6MAz7StrJQD0y3a1_-g97IxdtQenMNwhkSNp6wiLQsD0DzFr3zfLuIr_07ttOy07NknTJ9OPjneWQcONKUhQvLAfy-JsW4VwgOznwEcIT8K7ML-QpGXfNB1-igjm0b5x0ucHz76FQfLHxWGW2x9tsyg14NcKfpHlIsEDmHEooIGm0RCjYMuuo6uXfMCDIAMVwzUx4ehKZRXF3oNi--I889Gjfm2DeClhDYkg_ErasBgT2LLB1sLo2bPC8_65EDRQRE7sawDeyVa4sasasZ-OaN-E41dwu6re7tJcfbphpTgS9uMkkhhyic6HIwzg1iRk8sqo0_vQ6uAMtB7LDmSny7vN_3kNWFamR9u-_vOMwSW2sRZkf8S0QxjmuDmVkrH32iKx1dsszmXmtjuUtZoLr400LjNHXEb3MWUjbLWxL3u5xassasyX1LrcXYGLF3bPiZigX_Q3-8bFAHjV3-jvHxgIFd7NLtkR4socHO7Dx99ejDCnQ_sCoyFQVhRUE8iAA&state=H4sIAAAAAAAEAG2Oyw3CMAxAred4QH7EAO_SHKKgsgLhwQR0gTQ0JuHGVpF2SpXDFlZv1cd7tDwAkY0B_7WArc4cPNVJMZ_QTN9XjH6WNcg5JspU47EdSkYW3HIVthNW1MqRfx9JCIslkNTaeYCfKxDiEc56Xh1PRFhVm7un5nVmGpQ0Xz-MgX2l2E_qgomUnK9fS7SvSLXWmhoRYK0JYzMdd2twBvnWWUE3LAAAA0&session_state=e4d12345-4013-4edb-8487-35ef1763f323
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Run the network trace (or fiddler) and check what is the response  you have received? Also, I believe that `abc@domain.com` is the substituted string. It would be replaced with actual `userPrinicipalAddress`.

Comment: @user1672994  It is giving the error code 403 (Forbidden).

Comment: Do you get the same error when you run it from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?

Comment: @user1672994 it is working fine from developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: Just for additional information the application is not on azure but it is on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com

Comment: It seems that you are not passing the scope appropriately?

Answer (score 1):

The "access token" you've provided is *not* an Access Token. That is an Authorization Code that you would use to *obtain* an Access Token. More specifically, that is the redirection URI with query params that include the `code` you would submit.

You may want to take a look [at this primer I wrote](https://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/) on OAuth 2.0 and the v2 Endpoint. It will help with understanding how OAuth works and the various calls required to obtain an `access_token`.

---

In order to retrieve profile information, including `manager`, from another user (a `user` other than the one who is authenticated) you need one of the following permission scopes:

- `User.Read.All`
- `User.ReadWrite.All`
- `Directory.Read.All`
- `Directory.ReadWrite.All`
- `Directory.AccessAsUser.All`

You'll also need to obtain [Admin Consent](https://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-admin-consent/) before you can use these scopes.

Once you have both the correct Scope and Admin Consent, you can request the profile for another user with `/v1.0/users/{id}/manager`.

Comment: I am trying to retrieve the manager information from the same user itself. Also I have given all the permission required.

Comment: Can you add a copy of your token to your question?

Comment: LaFLuer Added the access token in question. Please help.

Comment: That isn't the **Access Token**, that is the **Authorization Code** that you would use to _obtain_ an Access Token.